# Custom label or translation in custom action in field service dispatcher console

Tags: administration, field-service-lightning, fieldservice, fsl

is possible to translate or use custom labels in "Custom actions" of the Field Service Dispatcher Console UI? There is a workaround to avoid the unique single language?

The field is indicated below

[image: print of the screen with the field valorized]